# Tire and elastic search query behavior

Tags: ruby-on-rails, search, elasticsearch, tire

I'm using Tire to wrap some search behavior in my Rails app. I'm not doing any special configuration yet, but I'm running into this issue here:

I have a `'foo bar'` string inside an indexed model, and if I search for either `'foo'` or `'foo bar'`, the record matches, but also if I'm doing a `'hello bar'`, the record is still found.

Is there any configuration that I can do to stop this from happening? Meaning something like if not all terms are found, discard that result

Comment: Set the default operator to AND

Comment: that did the trick. unfortunately there's no 'mark comment as correct answer' option :)

Comment: :) added an answer then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[As stated in the doc](https://github.com/karmi/tire), you can change the default operator, in your case, use `AND`

```
  query do
    string 'ruby python', :default_operator => 'AND'
  end
```